# Install Multiple Skypes on same Pc

Tags: windows, skype

Is there any possible way to install multiple skypes to different folders each? And have them run independently? I know i can run two instances of one installation using skype.exe /secondary but I need it to do this for something? Any idea how it can be done or if possible?

Comment: Have you simply tried to install it in another folder in the C:\? Then you can rename the shortcut and have "separate installs." Running them at the same time might cause an error to pop up regarding the same application already currently running.

Comment: Tried it just didnt open anything haha. I need to have separate instances of skype running

Comment: Only opened one

Comment: Another idea that is not answer worthy, but would get the results you want (kinda), is to use VMware Player (or similar product), to make a virtual machine that has the other version of Skype you want. I am guessing that would get you the results. But that is a lot more work thank you are hoping to do to achieve this. Maybe you could state in your question what your goal of this is. Maybe there is another way to get your results, other than installing multiple versions of Skype.

Comment: Yeah that is a ton of resources and im looking to write a program to manage different skype.exe's to make calls simultaneously. But they have to be independent.